# Helm string concatenation using other variables

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

In Helm *(using v3)* how can I build up a variable inside of a template using other variables? Assume I have the following:

```
{{- $def := index .Values "default" -}}
apiVersion: v1
data:
  POSTGRES_HOST: {{ $def.POSTGRES_HOST | b64enc | quote }}
  POSTGRES_USER: {{ $def.POSTGRES_USER | b64enc | quote }}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: {{ $def.POSTGRES_PASSWORD | b64enc | quote }}
  POSTGRES_DB: {{ $def.POSTGRES_DB | b64enc | quote }}
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: server
type: Opaque
```

I then want to do something like the following *(pseudocode)* using `+` as string concat:

```
DATABASE_URL: {{ "postgres://" + $def.POSTGRES_USER + ":" + $def.POSTGRES_PASSWORD + "@" + $def.POSTGRES_HOST + "/" + $def.POSTGRES_DB | b64enc | quote }}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the helm string function [printf](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#printf) for this.

```yaml
DATABASE_URL: {{ printf "postgres://%s:%s@%s/%s" $def.POSTGRES_USER $def.POSTGRES_PASSWORD $def.POSTGRES_HOST $def.POSTGRES_DB | b64enc | quote }}
```

#### printf

Returns a string based on a formatting string and the arguments to pass to it in order.

```
printf "%s has %d dogs." .Name .NumberDogs
```